# Pusher Channels Flutter is not working on iOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, pusher, pusherswift

It's working perfectly fine on Android devices, but I'm running into issues when testing on iOS devices. Specifically, the real-time communication feature doesn't seem to be working on iOS devices.

And I already did it
iOS specific installation #
The Pusher Channels Flutter plugin adds the pusher-websocket-swift cocoapod to your project. You probably need to run a

`$ pod install`
in the ios directory.

and this is my podfile.lock

```
  - pusher_channels_flutter (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - PusherSwift (~> 10.1.1)
  - PusherSwift (10.1.3):
    - NWWebSocket (~> 0.5.3)
    - TweetNacl (~> 1.0.0)
```

and also I opened this issue [pusher-channels-flutter/issues/115](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-channels-flutter/issues/115)

## I need help to build it on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Remove `authEndpoint: url` from the `init` function as it's only used in the web version, causing issues on iOS.

```dart
 await pusher.init(
        apiKey: 'f****************',
        cluster: 'eu',
        onConnectionStateChange: onConnectionStateChange,
        onError: onError,
        onSubscriptionSucceeded: onSubscriptionSucceeded,
        onEvent: onEvent,
        onSubscriptionError: onSubscriptionError,
        onDecryptionFailure: onDecryptionFailure,
        onMemberAdded: onMemberAdded,
        onMemberRemoved: onMemberRemoved,

        // authEndpoint: "<Your Authendpoint Url>",  Just delete this line
        
        onAuthorizer: onAuthorizer,
      );
```